# arabic letter in mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, arabic

I want to ask how to type Arabic letters inside numbers in mysql database

like "11D36" assume D is Arabic letter .

the Unicode is on utf-8 and real value are on "11D36" , but the column values when press browse in phpmyadmin it getting "1136D" so I'm trying to fix it but no luck

Comment: What is the type definition of your column?

Comment: 1) Is your database using UTF8 or "newer" collection for its configuration? [ run SHOW CREATE DATABASE and SHOW CREATE TABLE and provide the answer here ] 2) Is your data correctly stored inside the database? it could be that from PHP to MySQL the data is getting "garballed" due to latin1 (the default for MySQL) to utf8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table (pk, name) values (1, unhex('11D36'));
```